# Passing The ID of a Field in another Field of the same model Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

#### **Hello**, I am trying to pass the ID of a Model in an Image Field URL(upload_to) and then access it Through a URL unique to The instance.

> ***Here's What I did (Amature)***;
>
> ```
> class User(models.Model):
>    serial = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
>    profile = models.ImageField(upload_to=f"profiles/{serial}/")
> ```

*But all I'm Getting is OSError.*
I wanted to save the file to **`profiles/{serial}/`** directory in the app.
So Every Instance of the Model has its own Directory. And Then access it Through **`host:port/api/users/{serial}/profile.jpg`**
My View Set is served through **`host:port/api/users`**

Is there a way I can Do it?
Any Help is Highly Appreciated. A Detailed Explaination is Even more Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to

> upload_to may also be a callable, such as a function. This will be called to obtain the upload path, including the filename. This callable must accept two arguments and return a Unix-style path (with forward slashes) to be passed along to the storage system. The two arguments are: instance and filename

So you can do something like this

```py
def profile_handler(instance, file_name)
    return f"profiles/{instance.id}/{file_name}"

class User(models.Model):
   serial = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   profile = models.ImageField(upload_to=profile_handler)
```

Comment: Here, ```instance.id``` is returning None so the URL becomes ```api/users/profiles/None```. Any Solutions ?

Comment: Problem is that the instance isn't saved yet. Probably best to make your profile field nullable, save obj first, then set profile on obj.

Answer (score 0):

on model override save method like this

```
def save(self,*args, **kwargs):
    self.fieldname=currentmodel.objects.last().id+1
    super(Orders, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```